# Colocar mi formulario de acceso de devise en otra vista

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando colocar mi formulario de acceso de rails en mi vista principal, estoy siguiendo este tutorial [Cargar el formulario de login de devise desde otra vista](http://blog.en1mes.com/formularios-de-devise-como-vista-parcial/) pero me da un pequeño error con omniauth no se porque, supongo que no le esta haciendo referencia, este es el error:

> undefined local variable or method resource_class for

y me lo marca en esta linea: `<%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>` 
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?
 este es mi codigo:
application_helper

```
def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

y cargue el render en mi vista principal:

```
  <%= render :file => '/devise/sessions/new' %>
```

ademas de que estoy usando omniauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a poner esto en tu `application_helper.rb`

```
  def resource_class
    devise_mapping.to
  end
```

El problema puede ser que el artículo es de hace dos años atrás y quizás en ese entonces aún no era necesario usar `resource_class` desde la vista de devise (asumo que estás usando una versión más nueva).
De cualquier forma, si hay otro método faltante, podrías revisar los métodos que se encuentra como `protected` [desde el proyecto de devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L33) y copiar lo que necesites a tu helper.

Comment: HOLA @Alter Lagos GRACIAS POR TU RESPUESTA HERMANO me sirvio mucho, berro ya no encontraba como corregirlo, eso es lo malo de los tutoriales viejos :/ otra vez, MUCHAS GRACIAS